# Python pygame quit issue

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get my program to quit when the ESC key is pressed, but also if the windows exit button is clicked.

Currently I have this code:

```
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True
                break # break out of the for loop
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            break # break out of the for loop
    if done:
        break # to break out of the while loop

    # your game stuff
    for dict_containing_value in holdList:           
            i = dict_containing_value['value']
            #pygame.event.pump
            if (i=="("):
                drawBracketBox(bracketColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+25,(y+y+y)*50+25))

                x=x+1
            elif (i==")"):
                drawBracketBox(bracketColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+31,(y+y+y)*50+25))

                x=x+1
            elif (i=="IF"):
                drawFunctionBox(functionColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+21,(y+y+y)*50+22))

                x=x+1
            elif (i=="sum"):
                drawFunctionBox(functionColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render((i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+14,(y+y+y)*50+22))

                x=x+1
            elif (i=="+"):
                drawOperatorCircle(opColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+31,(y+y+y)*50+22))

                x=x+1
            elif (i=="-"):
                drawOperatorCircle(opColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+32,(y+y+y)*50+22))

                x=x+1
            elif (i=="*"):
                drawOperatorCircle(opColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+31,(y+y+y)*50+26))

                x=x+1
            elif (i=="/"):
                drawOperatorCircle(opColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+32,(y+y+y)*50+22))

                x=x+1
            else:
                drawConstantBox(constColor, x, y)
                label = myfont.render(str(i), 1, (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(label, ((x+x)*50+14,(y+y+y)*50+22))

                x=x+1
    pygame.display.update()
```

The current output is that continuously loops round my `for dict_containing_value in holdList:` loop which means that it prints out the output many times - which is not my desired result.

Please see the picture below (top picture is my current result, buttom is my desired result)
[image]

Comment: Where is the initial value for `x` set up? You *are* expecting the loop to run more than once, in general, right? (Otherwise, why did you write a loop?) What do you expect to happen to the value of `x` over time, and why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel They're defined just above where I started to copy from. Sorry for missing them out. They're just declared as x=1, y=1

Comment: Please post the complete code; where does `holdList` get defined? 
Also, your while loop is going to thrash while it continually checks for user input. Put a sleep in there (it can be for just 10 ms but it will stop your CPU from choking).

Comment: @AaronD Posting where holdList is defined would require posting majority of my code - I know that my for loop works, as it displays what is shown in the bottom half of my attached picture - however the issue is that when I run the program, the window stops responding straight away - so I figured it's because it needs to know when to exit?

Comment: The event checking code appears to be correct. If you've got a double buffered surface you're blitting to, you should `clear()` and `flip()` it every loop to avoid the overwriting problem you seem to be having. Also, since the `x` value is defined outside of the loop, it is never set to 1 for the next iteration of the `while not done` code.

Comment: add your full code to pastebin

Comment: Here is my full code http://pastebin.com/WXe4rjLe

Comment: example.JSON file: http://pastebin.com/mNCagxfj

Comment: You should use pygame.quit() in order to stop the program, otherwise the pygame-window stays open (and seems broken for the OS). I don't think that's the problem dough...

Comment: In your posted code the "your game stuff-for-loop" is should be one step more to the right, inside the main while-loop. Otherwise the program will just try to quit, but, since it misses the pygame.quit(), just freeze.

Comment: You need to fill the screen to overwrite the previous objects

Answer (score 0):

You could create a terminate function:

```
def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

and call terminate() when the escape key is pressed/released or/and when the quit event is called.

```
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    if done:
        terminate()
```

or

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            terminate()
```

or you could just call pygame.quit and sys.exit without a function:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for quit before keydown not after, as the ESC is also a Keydown event

Comment: your answer should have a lot of information, so that anyone can understand, this should be a comment